# NodeJs Flow Process

Tags: node.js

i recently started working on nodeJs. But got confused between single thread concept wile using global or var keyword variables across diffrent pages which are inluded using required. Below is my code.

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    var comm_fun = requre("./common_functions");
    var global_res = ''; // variable to send the reponse back to browser from any function
    var global_req = '';// variables to save request data


    app.listen(1234,function(req,res){

        console.log("server started");
        global_res = res;
        global_req = req;
        mysql = '';// code to have mysql connection in this variable
    });
```

now, as i can use mysql, global_res and global_req variables in diffrent files which are included. But will these effects the values for another request, as they are global.

for example, 
request 1 has value 1 for "global_req",

at same time request 2 comes

request 2 has value 2 for "global_req"

will these two request will collide at any point of time. can at any point of time can "global_req" be overwriten from 1 to 2 , as second request has arrived. Or both are diffrent request and will not collide at any point of time.

Thanks,

Comment: Did my answer help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and here's a very simple scenario:

1. Request 1 comes in, sets global ID to 1
2. Request 1 then performs some IO-bound operation (e.g. DB query)
3. Meanwhile request 2 comes in and sets the global ID to 2
4. The IO-bound operation completes and request 1 continues but the global ID is now 2 and not 1

The argument about Node being single-threaded is only applicable if your application is purely CPU-bound, however, given the majority of Node applications are *IO*-bound then they are in-effect multi-threading. The problem lies in the fact we can't guarantee the order in which callbacks will return, and with that in mind it's fairly simple to create a race condition e.g.

```
let global_id = 0;
...
app.use(() => global_id++);
app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const exists = db.query(`SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ${global_id}`);
    if (!exists) {
      db.query(`INSERT INTO ....`);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
});
```

If 2 requests hit the `/create` endpoint simultaenously, it would be *very* unlikely that both would succeed (at least correctly).

Comment: As far as I know in your scenario, because of event loop, request 1's query will be given to db before request 2's query. Since global ID is 1 when the query for request 1 is created, both request 1 and request 2 succeeds.

Comment: @ozata I don't think you fully understand how the event loop works in context of IO-bound operations, when an IO-bound call executes (e.g. a DB query), Node will continue to process other requests. So in the example above, when request 1 queries the DB, request 2 is also being processed at which point global ID has now changed, at that point request 1 now has invalid state... Now, there are other ways around this of course, but I'm trying to explain to the OP why his approach of using global data in this way is flawed.

Comment: so what should be the process, in such scanario

Comment: @Purushottamzende this completely depends on the purpose of your globals.

Comment: @James, i want to access one variable on any of the included file, like user id, date_time, req variable

Comment: @Purushottamzende what do you mean by "included file"? What do your globals represent?

Comment: can we get this conversation on chat. i think it will be too lengthy here to discuss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177564/discussion-between-james-and-purushottam-zende).